# Capturing or printing variables in bashrc with shell=True in run command of subprocess module

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am learning concurrency with *Python 3 Standard Library, 2nd Editio*n. Is there a way to get the `subprocess` module to use variables in my `.bashrc` when I set `shell=True`?

I tried adding `echo "something"` in my `.bashrc` and ran the following but I couldn't see `something` in the output but I could see `$HOME`.

```
import subprocess

completed = subprocess.run('echo $HOME', shell=True)

print('returncode:', completed.returncode)
```

Comment: That uses sh, not bash.

Comment: you need to `source` the shell rc file by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. But first, you need to execute *Bash*. Right now, you're executing `/bin/sh`, which *could* be Bash, but you don't want to assume. To fix that, pass in `executable` argument:

```py
import subprocess

completed = subprocess.run('echo $HOME',
    shell=True,
    executable='/usr/bin/bash'
)

print('returncode:', completed.returncode)
```

Now we have that out of the way, there are two ways to ensure your `.bashrc` is sourced. Since Bash is not running interactively, you need to *either*,

(A) `source` it yourself:

```py
import subprocess

completed = subprocess.run('source ~/.bashrc && echo "$HOME"',
    shell=True,
    executable='/usr/bin/bash'
)

print('returncode:', completed.returncode)
```

or,

(B) Use `BASH_ENV`:

```py
import subprocess

completed = subprocess.run('echo "$HOME"',
    env={'BASH_ENV': '~/.bashrc'},
    shell=True,
    executable='/usr/bin/bash'
)

print('returncode:', completed.returncode)
```

`BASH_ENV` is a variable used by Bash. If Bash sees the variable, and after expanding the variable (i.e. tilda expansion), the path is to a file that exists, it sources the variable before executing the rest of the script.